# Dynamics 365 CrmSvcUtils no longer connecting

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

Currently I'm hitting an issue with downloading the models into a cs class file using the CrmSvcUtils executable.

Connections to the Dynamics 365 need to be across TLS 1.1+ so in the application I've got I'm forcing to 1.2. However I can't seem to get this to work with the command line based CrmSvcUtils.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: Did you download the latest tools including crmsvcutil from [nuget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/download-tools-nuget)?

Comment: That's the answer, Thanks Arun, If you promote you're comment to a response I'll flag it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download the latest Core Tools from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreTools) store & replace.

Powershell for the same:

```
$sourceNugetExe = "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe"
$targetNugetExe = ".\nuget.exe"
Remove-Item .\Tools -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore
Invoke-WebRequest $sourceNugetExe -OutFile $targetNugetExe
Set-Alias nuget $targetNugetExe -Scope Global -Verbose

##
##Download CoreTools
##
./nuget install  Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreTools -O .\Tools
md .\Tools\CoreTools
$coreToolsFolder = Get-ChildItem ./Tools | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreTools.'}
move .\Tools\$coreToolsFolder\content\bin\coretools\*.* .\Tools\CoreTools
Remove-Item .\Tools\$coreToolsFolder -Force -Recurse

##
##Remove NuGet.exe
##
Remove-Item nuget.exe
```

[Read more.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/download-tools-nuget)